# Is there a way to run Javascript without a browser, like a shell or batch script?

Tags: script, javascript

Is there a way one could run Javascript the way Python, Bash, Windows Batch or other scripting languages are run?

File access and other library functions would be nice but are not required - I'm just most fluent and most efficient in Javascript these days. Opening up a browser console each time is rather uncomfortable, though.

I'd be most interested in Windows environment.

Comment: Node.js is the most widely used, frequently maintained and most standard JavaScript shell you can find. It will allow you to run the latest JavaScript features.

Answer (score 22):

#### Is there a way to run JavaScript without a browser, like a shell or batch script?

What you are looking for are [JavaScript shells](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Shells).

> A JavaScript shell allows you to quickly test snippets of JavaScript
> code without having to reload a web page. They are extremely useful
> for developing and debugging code.

---

#### Standalone JavaScript shells

> The following JavaScript shells are stand-alone environments, like
> perl or python.
>
> - [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) - Node.js is a platform for easily building fast, scalable network applications.
> - [JSDB](http://www.jsdb.org/) - A standalone JavaScript shell, with compiled binaries for Windows, Mac, and Linux.
> - [JavaLikeScript](http://javalikescript.free.fr/) - A standalone, extensible JavaScript shell including both native and JavaScript libraries.
> - [GLUEscript](http://gluescript.sourceforge.net/) - A standalone JavaScript shell for writing cross-platform JavaScript applications.  It can use wxWidgets for GUI
>   apps, and was formerly called wxJavaScript.
> - [jspl](http://jspl.msg.mx/) - A standalone JavaScript shell enhanced by Perl. Can use perl modules directly from JavaScript: DBI for database integration,
>   GTK2 for GUI apps, POSIX for system programming, etc. The best of CPAN
>   now for JavaScript programmers.
> - [ShellJS](http://shelljs.org/) - Portable Unix shell commands for Node.js
> - [Windows Script Host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) - Microsoft® Windows® Script Host (WSH) is a language-independent scripting host for Windows Script.

Source [JavaScript shells](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Shells)

Comment: +1 Thank you, that's a very thorough answer! The jspl and GLUEScript look very interesting, that's exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 12):

[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) is what you're looking for.

It's based on V8, the same JavaScript engine that Chrome uses. You can use it as a REPL or run scripts from `.js` files.

Node.js's popularity in commercial projects is increasing recently. It's used for servers that have to handle many parallel connections. It's also used for development purposes, for example [Bower](http://bower.io/) (front-end development package manager) is written completely in JavaScript and intended to run on Node.js.

Answer (score 7):

For the sake of completeness one have to mention [Windows Scripting Host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k.aspx), which is available from Windows 98 and higher and is able to [execute JavaScript code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xazzc41b.aspx):

```
CScript.exe c:\scripts\sample.js
```

Comment: +1 That's what I wanted, thank you! Shame I couldn't find it myself even though it's already available on my Windows.

Comment: @PavelPetrman Small note: Windows Scripting Host uses IE's JavaScript engine (`jscript.dll` or `jscript9.dll`), so keep that in mind when writing code. More details: [How will the Chakra Jscript engine be exposed to Scripting Hosts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084927/how-will-the-chakra-jscript-engine-be-exposed-to-scripting-hosts), [Any info on forcing IE9 to use jscript.dll instead of jscript9.dll?](http://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/n34lk/any_info_on_forcing_ie9_to_use_jscriptdll_instead/).

Answer (score 4):

Check out [RunJS](https://runjs.dev/)

I recently have started using RunJS on my mac - it is such a great tool and helps me immensely to test out things quickly.

RunJS is available for the **Windows** machine as well. You can find download link [here](https://github.com/lukehaas/RunJS/releases/tag/v1.7.0)